# Go lang decode io.read JSON v.s. unmarshal giving different results

Tags: json, go

I have a handler like this:

```
type Location struct {
  Lat  float32 `json:"lat"`
  Lon  float32 `json:"lon"`
}



func handleJSONLocation(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {    
    b := new(Location)
    var bb Location;
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(req.Body)

    json.Unmarshal(buf.Bytes(), &bb)
    json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(b)

    log.Printf("%s %f,%f %f,%f", buf.String(), b.Lat, b.Lon, bb.Lat, bb.Lon);

    data, _ := json.Marshal("{'location':'saved'}")
    res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    res.Write(data)
}
```

I get

```
2014/04/25 22:05:55 {"lat":42.9635013,"lon":-81.22387210000001} 0.000000,0.000000 42.963501,-81.223869
```

Why doesn't `b` object get decoded into?

Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run the following code, the entire body of the HTTP request is read into `buf`:

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
buf.ReadFrom(req.Body)
```

At this point, further reads from `req.Body` will result in an `EOF` error.  So when you attempt to decode into `b`, you are getting an error, which would be visible if you checked the return value with something like:

```
if err := json.NewDecoder(req.Body).Decode(b); err != nil {
    log.Println("Could not decode body:", err)
}
```

It would also be wise to check the error on the other function calls you make.

Since you've already read the request body into a memory buffer though, you could create a new `bytes.Buffer` to pass to APIs that expect an `io.Reader` (such as `json.NewDecoder`).

Comment: If one uses `ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)` to debug and does json decode afterwards, there will also exists an EOF error.

Comment: Your comment definitely saved me some minutes :)

Comment: Is there a best practice or most common way devs are handling this? If I have many endpoints I have to handle this for each. So I hardly see the use that Go flushes after reading from req.Body ...